# Laravel 5.6.7 тесты и показ сообщений

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Как в тестировании Laravel 5.6.7 (я использую phpunit) сделать вывод сообщения в случае ошибки непосредственно во время или после assertStatus()? Нужна информация о том, что именно не сработало.

Могу выводить сообщения перед ассертом при помощи банального echo, но это не совсем удобно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, есть одна мысль.
Поскольку в классе TestResponse отсутствует возможность вставлять сообщения в assert'ы, можно класс теста представить в виде мелких методов, тестирующих конкретный аспект. Тогда при провале теста имя метода будет выступать сообщением, а конкретный проваленный ассерт - только уточнение, что именно было провалено. Поскольку методы assertXxx возвращают $this, их легко связать в цепочку, описывающую ожидаемый результат. Ну, типа

```
public function testValidationPage() {
    $response = $this->get('/validate');
    $response->assertStatus(200)->assertSeeText($controlText)->assertLocation($uri);
}
```

Соответственно, при провале теста будет выведено имя метода и проваленный ассерт. Если все реальные тесты разбить на тесты по тестируемым факторам - имя метода и имя ассерта станут "говорящими". Правда, тестов будет куда больше, чем в случае собранного вместе десятка assertStatus'ов.
Как-то так...